# how to transform a subset vertex of a vertex of human skeleton in directx3d?

Tags: c++, math, animation, transform, direct3d

I want to transform a vertex (such as a vecotr) by a matrix， but i can not find the api like a vector multiply matrix in direct9 msdn 。so my question is that：should i code it by myself，or is there any other method can achieve it？

Comment: [D3DXVec3Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205520(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the D3DX utility library: [d3dx msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

specifically: [D3DXVec3Transform msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

D3DX library has been deprecated for Win8: [D3DXMath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use the [XMVector3Transform method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector3transform%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the D3DXMath library.